# Selecting only first-level elements from $(this)

Tags: jquery

I'd like to select, from $(this) selector, the fist-level input hidden field. Tried with :

```
$(this).find('> input[type="hidden"]')
```

But seems it select nothing.

HTML looks like :

```
<div id="pollo">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" />
        <input type="hidden" />
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" />
            </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" />
</div>
```

Comment: Well, what does your HTML look like?

Comment: And which div `this` refers to  here?

Comment: If `this` is `#pollo`, it's clear why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "first-level" elements are called `children` and as such, you find them using the `children()` method:

```
$(this).children('input[type=hidden]')
```

Comment: Plus this is a simpler selector

Answer (score 0):

Your tag should have an ID, then you can use.

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');

$('#' + id + ' > input[type="hidden"]')...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, bizarre. Ensure that `this` is in fact the parent element. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X5Mh9/) with an example.

### HTML

```
<div id="box-1">
    <input type="hidden" value="I'm in box 1" />
    <div id="box-2">
        <input type="hidden" value="I'm in box 2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$(function()
{
    $('#box-1').find('> input[type="hidden"]').each(function()
    {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
​
```

Answer (score 0):

After the [**jQuery API**](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) you should place `this` like this in this case:

```
$('> input[type="hidden"]', this)
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JCyEV/1)

Comment: And that would be exactly the same as `$(this).find('> input[type="hidden"]')` !

Comment: @adeneo yes but actually not because it's not working, and it's not working because jQuery doesn't knows what the parent of the child element is if you're doing it like this.